# Ping Server Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ping

I want to ping one of our server and also keep rotating the file. For that I have created the below script

```
function main()
{
    ping 192.168.1.1 > E:\Ping\TestCon.txt
    RotateLog
}

function RotateLog {
$log = "E:\Ping\*.log_old"
$target = Get-ChildItem $log -Filter "*.log_old" | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1
# $threshold = 3000
$datetime = Get-Date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d"
$filename = "$("TestCon")_${datetime}.log_old"
if ( $filename -eq $targeta.name )
    {
        main
    }
else
    {
        $newname = "$("TestCon")_${datetime}.log_old"
        Rename-Item -Path "E:\Ping\TestCon.txt" $newname
        main
    }

}

main
```

Issue is when this returns to main it creates new file but I want to append it as long  as it is of same date. Kindly suggest

Comment: Why not just write directly to a file named `TestCon_${datetime}.log_old`?

Answer (score 1):

Either you do as Mathias R. Jessen suggested in the comment and write directly to the file.

```
$datetime = Get-Date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d"
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 192.168.1.1 | Out-File -Path "TestCon_${datetime}.log_old"
```

Or you can test whether the file exists and append the content.

```
if ([bool](Test-Path -Path "TestCon_${datetime}.log_old"))
{
  Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 192.168.1.1 | Out-File -Path "TestCon_${datetime}.log_old" -Append
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias R. Jessen and Alex_P... It worked.. Actually was searching for Append Parameter and -Append helps.. thanks a ton guys.. :)